# Regex scan fails

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to parse all money from a string. For example, I want to extract:

```
['$250,000', '$3.90', '$250,000', '$500,000']
```

from:

```
'Up to $250,000………………………………… $3.90 Over $250,000 to $500,000'
```

The regex:

```
\$\ ?(\d+\,)*\d+(\.\d*)?
```

seems to match all money expressions as in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/OgX1NI/1). However, when I try to `scan` on Ruby, it fails to give me the desired result.

```
s # => "Up to $250,000 $3.90 Over $250,000 to $500,000, add$3.70 Over $500,000 to $1,000,000, add..$3.40 Over $1,000,000 to $2,000,000, add...........$2.25\nOver $2,000,000 add ..$2.00"
r # => /\$\ ?(\d+\,)*\d+\.?\d*/
s.scan(r)
# => [["250,"], [nil], ["250,"], ["500,"], [nil], ["500,"], ["000,"], [nil], ["000,"], ["000,"], [nil], ["000,"], [nil]]
```

From `String#scan` docs, it looks like this is because of the group. How can I parse all the money in the string?

Comment: `s.scan(/\$[\d,.]+/)`. Edit: read your question again, you probably want to make sure that the amount is in right pattern as well (with comma or periods), my regex will also match with strings like "$3,.0"

Comment: The regex you are mentioning and the regex that you have in your code as `r` are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your regular expression, which I'll write in *free-spacing mode* so I can document it:

```
r = /
    \$     # match a dollar sign
    \ ?    # optionally match a space (has no effect) 
    (      # begin capture group 1
      \d+  # match one or more digits
      ,    # match a comma (need not be escaped)
    )*     # end capture group 1 and execute it >= 0 times
    \d+    # match one or more digits
    \.?    # optionally match a period
    \d*    # match zero or more digits
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

In non-free-spacing mode this would be written as follows.

```
r = /\$ ?(\d+,)*\d+\.?\d*/
```

When a regex is defined in free-spacing mode all spaces are stripped out before the regex is evaluated, which is why I had to escape the space. That's not necessary when the regex is not defined in free-spacing mode.

It is nowhere needed to match a space after the dollars sign, so `\ ?` should be removed. Suppose now we have

```
r = /\$\d+\.?\d*/
"$2.31 cat $44. dog $33.607".scan r
  #=> ["$2.31", "$44.", "$33.607"]
```

That works, but it is questionable whether you want to match values that do not have exactly two digits after the decimal point.

Now write

```
r = /\$(\d+,)*\d+\.?\d*/
"$2.31 cat $44. dog $33.607".scan r
  #=> [[nil], [nil], [nil]]
```

To see why this result was obtained examine the doc for [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan), specifically the last sentence of the first paragraph: " If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.".

We can avoid that problem by changing the capture group to a non-capture group:

```
r = /\$(?:\d+,)*\d+\.?\d*/
"$2.31 cat $44. dog $33.607".scan r
  #=> ["$2.31", "$44.", "$33.607"]
```

Now consider this:

```
"$2,241.31 cat $1,2345. dog $33.607".scan r
  #=> ["$2,241.31", "$1,2345.", "$33.607"]
```

which is still not quite right. Try the following.

```
r = /
    \$          # match a dollar sign
    \d{1,3}     # match one to three digits
    (?:,\d{3})  # match ',' then 3 digits in a nc group
    *           # execute the above nc group >=0 times
    (?:\.\d{2}) # match '.' then 2 digits in a nc group
    ?           # optionally match the above nc group
    (?![\d,.])  # no following digit, ',' or '.'
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode

"$2,241.31 $2 $1,234 $3,6152 $33.607 $146.27".scan r
  #=> ["$2,241.31", "$2", "$1,234", "$146.27"]
```

`(?![\d,.])` is a *negative lookahead*.

In normal mode this regular expression is written as follows.

```
r = /\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?(?![\d,.])/
```

The following erroneous result would obtain without the negative lookahead at the end of the regex.

```
r = /\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?/
"$2,241.31 $2 $1,234 $3,6152 $33.607 $146.27".scan r
  #=> ["$2,241.31", "$2", "$1,234", "$3,615", "$33.60",
  #    "$146.27"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
[3] pry(main)> str = <<EOF
[3] pry(main)* Up to $250,000………………………………… $3.90 Over $250,000 to $500,000, add………………$3.70 Over $500,000 to $1,000,000, add……………..$3.40 Over $1,000,000 to $2,000,000, add……...........$2.25
[3] pry(main)* Over $2,000,000 add …..………………………$2.00
[3] pry(main)* EOF
=> "Up to $250,000………………………………… $3.90 Over $250,000 to $500,000, add………………$3.70 Over $500,000 to $1,000,000, add……………..$3.40 Over $1,000,000 to $2,000,000, add……...........$2.25\nOver $2,000,000 add …..………………………$2.00\n"
[4] pry(main)> str.scan /\$\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*/
=> ["$250,000", "$3.90", "$250,000", "$500,000", "$3.70", "$500,000", "$1,000,000", "$3.40", "$1,000,000", "$2,000,000", "$2.25", "$2,000,000", "$2.00"]
[5] pry(main)>
```